# No data showing in dojox.grid.DataGrid

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using dojo 1.3 and having problems getting this dojox.grid.DataGrid working. I am sure it is my ignorance. I have been reading over the Dojo Campus examples and beleive I have right. My html looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid");
dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore");
</script>

    <div dojoType="dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore" jsId="forumsStore" url="action/forum.JsonForums"></div>

    <div id="ForumsListingArea" name="ForumsListingArea">
        <div id="ListOfForumsContainer" name="ListOfForumsContainer">
            <table dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" query="{ID:'*'}" store="forumsStore" clientSort="true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"  id="ListOfForums" name="ListOfForums">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th field="title" width="200px">Title</th>
                        <th field="commentCount" width="200px"># Of Posts</th>
                        <th field="description" width="200px">Moderators</th>
                        <th width="200px">Del|Config</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The firebug showes the data returned from the datastore as:

```
{identifier:"ID",items:[{"ID":"1","description":"Test Forum","title":"Test","topics":[],"commentCount":"0"}]}
```

When the content is rendered I get the table columns listed but there is no data displayed. Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This one is definitely not your fault.  Try changing the style on your table from:

```
style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
```

to something like this:

```
style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"
```

I am not sure how it works inside, but I find the grid code is almost unusable because of stuff like this.  Too many "features" for my liking.

I hope this works for you, it fixed it for me on version 1.2.3.

Comment: Are you suggesting I am setting myself up for many more problems? It would be easy enough to whip out the list of row myself.

Comment: The declarative field bindings add quite a bit of value, so I wouldn't say it is not worth the headaches.  I guess it depends on the nature of the data you are showing and how grid-like you need to be. 

Another problem: the grid cells have to be exactly the same height.  In most grids, this is the case (one line of text).  But for my use case, I had one row that was a paragraph of text, each a different size.  This causes some strange behavior when you scroll down a large list.  It is not easy to debug.

Comment: I have been banging my head for the whole day and suddenly 'style="width:900px;height:300px"', and it show up. If it's not for the nice integration in dojo, and the rich UI, and datastore, not to mention internalization, I would have left dojo for good.

Answer (score 1):

try removing the identifier, this is what I used, and it worked for me
{items:[{"Title":"HelloTitle","Year":"2010","Producer":"foo"},{"Title":"HelloTitle2","Year":"2110","Producer":"f2232312164oo"}]}

Comment: I had a somewhat similar problem (although I am loading the grid in code) and removing the identifier fixed it also. However, can you explain why this resolves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same crap happen to me in v1.7.1, and what fixed it for me was indeed giving the grid a fixed height like

```
#grid { height:500px !important; }
```

Without the `!important` it didn't work because, for some obscure reason, dojo kept assigning an inline style of 0px height to that element...